# use fixed string before slug or not

Tags: seo, url-slug

I'm caught in a discussion with a colleague about using a fixed string before using a slug or not. The aim off course is to rank better at search engines.

The site involves hotel travels. And the exact question is, should the URL be:

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/the-hilton-berlin
```

or

```
http://www.ourdomain.com/hotels/the-hilton-berlin
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Another similar question is: should common words (such as `the`, `of` but also `hotel`) be removed from the slug itself if it is contained? So in the above example the word `the` would be removed from the slug.

Comment: I explain this rather well in: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Sorry but this question seems to be duplicate of many already on the Pro Webmasters.