# Optimal URL structure for directory-like site

Tags: seo, url

I'm building a site where organic SEO is *very* important for me. It's a niche, there's very little competition, and any edge I can get will help me out tremendously. That being said, which URL structure would you suggest is best, for both technical reasons, and SEO?

- `example.com/dining` (HUB for all dining)
- `example.com/dining/restaurants` (HUB specifically for restaurants)
- `example.com/dining/cafes` (HUB specifically for cafes)
- `example.com/dining/restaurants/red-onion-club` (actual page for that venue)

Or

- `example.com/dining` (HUB for all dining)
- `example.com/dining/restaurants` (HUB specifically for restaurants)
- `example.com/dining/cafes` (HUB specifically for cafes)
- `example.com/venues/red-onion-club` (actual page for that venue)

Note I will also have hotels, bars, etc., with the same structure (give or take sub categories).

---

Which of these is best?

Someone made an argument for the the second set, as the flat URLs are shorter, don't tie any location to a specific category (if a bar was also a restaurant, and vice versa), and if I change any naming conventions, the URLs never change, because they're all at `/venues/the-location`. However, the first set of URLs contains keywords in the URL that let users and search engines know exactly what they are. If it's a restaurant, it's in the URL, if it's a bar, it's in the URL.

As I said, I have both of these working on the technical side, I just need to know which I should go forward with.

Comment: This answer will explain a lot of how this stuff works: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 There is a bit more to the picture than meets the eye.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the first set but without dining in last 3. However, you need to take care of the technical side.

- `example.com/dining` (HUB for all dining)
- `example.com/restaurants` (HUB specifically for restaurants)
- `example.com/cafes` (HUB specifically for cafes)
- `example.com/restaurants/red-onion-club` (actual page for that venue)