# SEO repeated keywords in domain and url

Tags: seo

For example i have the domainname buyhouse.com The keywords "buy house new york"

```
buyhouse.com/new-york/ 

buyhouse.com/buy-house-new-york/
```

Whats the best url option for SEO?

Comment: You will want to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 It explains the mechanics behind the scenes on how URL/URIs are handled. For the rest of it, if you have searchable terms in the URL, it is not necessary to place them in URI too. So your first example is best.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is best...

The best would be a domain name that you love, can brand and your customers will remember.

The perfect formula for a good URL is something your visitors can read and understand just glancing, they trust Google enough that the page is relevant, and this is why its a fact that shorter domains and urls tend to be favored, hence why 2 letter domains are more expensive than 3 letters, 4 letters and so forth.

The URL name is generally best short, so `example.com/new-york`, this informs the user that the page is indeed about New York. Then your title and meta description gives them more confidence.

This mere example would work well:

- path: `example.com/new-york/`
- title: Property Estates in New York
- meta: View hundreds of affordable properties and estates in new york, great for first time buyers.
- h1: Short readible header that tells them what the page is about in as few words as possible.
- Page: One of the many things missed when publishing content is that people tend to forget that keywords are written on the page, even if those keywords are not in the title, url, or meta doesn't nessacary you can't rank, in fact many sites rank for keywords when missing all of the above.

When building a site you should always put your customers and visitors first.

Comment: Nicely said! One thing I did not think about necessarily was the domain name. You made an important point on that. Domain names should be either for branding (company name) or for memorability and ease of use. Also your point on the domain name kind of disappearing in the SERPs and the user trusting the search engine is important to remind people about.

Answer (score 1):

Google is aiming for relevant content with keywords inside the content. If you have "buy house new york" in your URL but not on the page, you might as well have not bothered with the URL in the first place.

Personally I'd stick with the `new-york` URL, as it's fairly obvious to Google you buy homes anyway.