# Impact of use of specific terms in slug on SEO

Tags: seo, title, url-slug

Lets say there are two websites A and B and both have an article with exactly similar title but almost similar content. However, the URL structure of the two articles is as follows:

- Site A: `www.site-a.com/**article**/article-title.html`
- Site B: `www.site-b.com/**news**/article-title.html`

The difference between the above two URLs is that while A is using "article" in slug, while site B is using "news" in slug. Is there any meaningful difference in terms of SEO for these two sites. Please solve this query of mine, which might be arising out of my ignorance but I have seen that site B despite of having poorer content, ranks higher than A. 
Or in other words, what can be possible impact if site A also uses "news" in the slug.

Comment: You misunderstand the term "slug".  In fact you have different URLs, not different slugs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug

Comment: Ok, sorry for my ignorance. I am actually trying to find out if really keywords in url structure matter. I mean should one pay attention while choosing category / section name? In terms of seo, which of these is better? www.mysite.com/news/ or www.mysite.com/wiki/ or www.mysite.com/articles/ for a site which has a section with wikipedia like articles on contemporary matters.

Comment: There is so much that goes into a sites performance that it is nearly impossible to really determine how these sites should perform compared to each other. There are likely several positive factors that appear in site b versus site a that makes it perform better and not just the URI (in this case). However, to give you an idea of how the URI works in search, you may want to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639