# Using sub-directory vs single directory urls

Tags: seo, url, http, directory, subdirectory

I'm creating a location based site and was debating between two styles of writing urls. The first shows the name of the restaurant followed by the city its located in.

```
example.com/hillstone-new-york
```

The other would be a sub-directory in the form of the city and state followed by just the name of the restaurant:

```
example.com/new-york-ny/hillstone
```

From an SEO and overall usability perspective which of the two would be most advantageous?

Comment: You will want to see this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions and answers regarding URL structure on Pro Webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the better one - both from an SEO and organisation of data point of view.

Comment: It would be best to help the OP with an explanation of how you come to this conclusion so that the OP understands the issue.

Comment: True, but you'd already pointed to an earlier post which contain sufficient detail, so I just wanted to provide a quick answer and if they want the details, they can read the posts with detail.

Comment: My apologies, I guess I was not being clear. My comment is mostly for the future. I like that you are here and participating! When anyone starts out here, someone will come along and give advice from time to time to help you participate in the site. We all needed guidance when we first started. I certainly do not mean any offense, but hoped instead to give a guiding hand. Welcome to the site! Cheers!!

Comment: Oh no offence taken! Thanks for the pointer - it's definitely taken in the spirit it was intended :)