# URL structures for SEO

Tags: seo, url

I was just wondering what is the best way to structure my URL and if my URLs are holding me back from an SEO point of view.

Currently we have our categories URL displaying key words form that category but the contain numbers at the end of the URL for example

```
http://www.example.co.uk/nike-shoes-c-31.html
```

Would it be better or have an affect on our rankings if we just had

```
http://www.example.co.uk/nike-shoes.html
```

Then the subcategory to this would be

```
http://www.example.co.uk/nike-shoes-c-31_110.html
```

Would it be better if we explain our on page content a bit better in the sub category URL for example

```
http://www.example.co.uk/nike-shoes-latest-designs.html
```

Comment: This answer can help you understand a bit of what happens: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Ok but is it bad SEO practice to have number and letter (-c-31.html) in a url or will it have no impact ?

Comment: It will neither hurt or help you unless someone searches for *c 31* - then you are golden! ;-)

Comment: ok cheers, i didn't want to spend ages changing all my url to have no numbers at the end for it to have no affect

Comment: I understand. I went through a similar exercise and in the end, and it did not really make a difference. I did this for my own reasons as I redeployed the site and will make more changes again in a bit. My site gets very little attention mostly because I experiment around with it too much and Google scrambles to keep up... ;-) This is how I know what works and what does not.

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions on Pro Webmasters regarding URL structure.  You should be able to find answers from the [290+ related questions](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=url+structure+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 1):

1. Whenever possible, use a single domain & subdomain
2. The more readable by human beings, the better
3. Keywords in URLs: still a good thing
4. Multiple URLs serving the same content? Canonicalize 'em!
5. Exclude dynamic parameters when possible
6. Shorter > longer
7. Match URLs to titles most of the time (when it makes sense)
8. Including stop words isn't necessary
9. Remove/control for unwieldy punctuation characters
10. Limit redirection hops to two or fewer
11. Fewer folders is generally better
12. Avoid hashes in URLs that create separate/unique content
13. Be wary of case sensitivity
14. Hyphens and underscores are preferred word separators
15. Keyword stuffing and repetition are pointless and make your site look spammy

Reference:
https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls