# How should a search for listing results change the URL?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting

I have a realty site powered by selecting various options from dropdowns to find the right property. How should the listing results URLs be for SEO?

Should they all be under a single URL:

```
/listing-search-results/
```

Or should each option put a piece into the URL:

```
/apartments/under-100/?location=London
```

How does this work in terms of SEO? If I had to Google "2 bedroom house in London", how would a site with all the listings under a single URL show up in the search results?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question @Stephen, but just to clarify -> the website linked isn't mine, it's just one that has a query function similar to what I am wanting to build

Comment: Does this answer help?? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL should be short and describe your page content. 
I prefer

> /apartments/under-100/?location=London

Descriptive is better than numbers