# SEO - link closer to TLD vs. folder structure with keyword

Tags: seo, google, ranking, google-ranking

Let's say I want to build just another voucher code website (don't worry, I don't) and also I'd like to categorize my listed shops. What would be the best URL structure?

**My ideas are as follows:**

*Idea 1:*

> www.example.com/voucher - overview of all shops with codes (with
>   pagination)
>
> www.example.com/voucher/shoes-c1 - filtering by category,
>   ID 1 (c1)
>
> www.example.com/voucher/amazon-s1 - the **important**
>   landing page, ID 1 (s1)

So maybe you have seen that I would use s or c to determine weather it's a shop or a category.

*Idea 2:*

> www.example.com/voucher
>
> www.example.com/voucher/cat/shoes-1
>
> www.example.com/voucher/amazon-1

*Idea 3:*

> www.example.com/voucher
>
> www.example.com/voucher/shoes-1
>
> www.example.com/amazon-1

This looks clean to me but I would lose the "voucher" keyword at the most important landing page.

*Idea 4:*

> www.example.com/voucher
>
> www.example.com/voucher/shoes-1
>
> www.example.com/amazon-voucher-1

I've read very much on the internet about this topic and there are so many different opinions. Some people say that a keyword is important. And some other will tell you that the important pages should be as close as possible to the TLD.

So what's the right way?

Comment: I answered this question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Thanks. So I think /voucher/amazon would be the best even if people would rather write "amazon voucher" according to your answer. Still I don't know how the categories fit in this whole concept.

Comment: I do not know what you have in mind for a category, however, you simply have to think in terms are largest to smallest in size of definition/scope from left to right. For examples cars is larger than fiat which is larger than 500 which is larger than abarth. It is both an organizational and semantic argument rather than anything else. For example, if I was searching the web for a particular car to buy, I would be typing *fiat 500 abarth*. The two are the same. It is how we think.