# Menu / URL structure for SEO

Tags: seo, url, navigation

I am planning to structure my menu and following 4 types came into my mind.

**Menu 1**

```
Extensions (/extensions)
    |-- Magento Extensions (/extensions/magento)
    |-- Prestashop Extensions (/extensions/prestashop)
    |-- WooCommerce Extensions (/extensions/woocommerce)
Themes (/themes)
    |-- Magento Themes (/themes/magento)
    |-- Prestashop Themes (/extensions/prestashop)
    |-- WooCommerce Themes (/extensions/woocommerce)
Free Stuff (/free-stuff)
```

- Looks cleaner to me & require less space to fit in menu.
- More Sub-Categories/Types can be added easily under `Extensions` & `Themes`
- `Free Stuff` generalizes all the Free stuff from  `Extensions` & `Themes`

**Menu 2**

```
Extensions (/extensions)
        |-- Magento Extensions (/extensions/magento-extensions)
        |-- Prestashop Extensions (/extensions/prestashop-extensions)
        |-- WooCommerce Extensions (/extensions/woocommerce-extensions)
    Themes (/themes)
        |-- Magento Themes (/themes/magento-themes)
        |-- Prestashop Themes (/extensions/prestashop-themes)
        |-- WooCommerce Themes (/extensions/woocommerce-themes)
    Free Stuff (/free-stuff)
```

- This menu is exactly same as #1. It only differs in url structure - prefix has been added to sub-menu.

**Menu 3**

```
Magento (/magento)
    |-- Free Stuff (/magento/free-stuff)
    |-- Premium Extensions (/magento/premium-extensions)
    |-- Premium Themes (/magento/premium-themes)
Prestashop (/prestashop)
    |-- Free Stuff (/prestashop/free-stuff)
    |-- Premium Extensions (/prestashop/premium-extensions)   
    |-- Premium Themes (/prestashop/premium-themes) 
WooCommerce (/woocommerce)
    |-- Free Stuff (/woocommerce/free-stuff)
    |-- Premium Extensions (/woocommerce/premium-extensions)
    |-- Premium Themes (/woocommerce/premium-themes)
```

- Require more space in menu.
- If you want to add New Type(Drupal, Joomla etc.), you have to be careful with the available space in menu.

**Menu 4**

```
Magento (/magento)
    |-- Free Stuff (/magento/magento-free-stuff)
    |-- Premium Extensions (/magento/magento-premium-extensions)
    |-- Premium Themes (/magento/magento-premium-themes)
Prestashop (/prestashop)
    |-- Free Stuff (/prestashop/prestashop-free-stuff)
    |-- Premium Extensions (/prestashop/prestashop-premium-extensions)   
    |-- Premium Themes (/prestashop/prestashop-premium-themes)   
WooCommerce (/woocommerce)
    |-- Free Stuff (/woocommerce/woocommerce-free-stuff)
    |-- Premium Extensions (/woocommerce/woocommerce-premium-extensions)
    |-- Premium Themes (/woocommerce/woocommerce-premium-themes)
```

- This menu is exactly same as #3. It only differs in url structure - prefix has been added to sub-menu

Moreover, I am targeting for following keywords:

- "Magento Extensions"
- "Free Magento Extensions"
- "Magento Themes"
- "Free Magento Themes"

and similar goes for `Prestashop` & `Woocommerce`

Which menu structure should I implement in terms of SEO friendliness? or I should adopt a new structure. 
Please do suggest.

Comment: This answer will make your decisions regarding URL structure extremely clear: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Still confusing as compared to by keywords.

Comment: Do not be keyword focused. It is a myth perpetuated by so-called SEO experts that are not technical people and have not read the original research papers or patents. Any search term match is incidental after the fact. No search terms matches are actually made. It is all about semantic analysis and for Google always has been. Be natural. Be conversational. Create for users.

Comment: Suppose If I chose Menu 1 and focus on "Magento Extensions" keywords, the url "extensions/magento" should not matter? In your opinion which one looks for SEO friendly?

Comment: Now that I take a second look, I am still drinking my coffee so the brain is till warming up, I like the organization of the first menu best. As well, it really does not pay to repeat terms in a URL or navigational link. By tradition, these should be short, sweet, and make sense organizationally and so any semantic analysis on these should really reflect what they are and not force the issue. I see keyword optimizing as a akin to pounding a square peg into a round hole when a round peg is within reach. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @closetnoc. So that means even I use "/extensions/magento" I can target for "Magento Extensions" by using them in page title, h1 tag, anchor text etc. For example: <a href="/extensions/magento" title="Magento Extensions">Magento Extensions</a>

Comment: Bingo! You got it!! The most important clues are the title tag, h1 tag, description meta-tag, link text, URL/URI, then content. Nothing else really matters. For your links to these pages in content, make sure the link text is semantically complete with a subject, predicate, and object, just like you learned in school. Navigation is expected to be short. It has to be. But for everything else, using full sentences or significant portions of a sentence is far superior.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to differentiate two things:

- menu (which is **mostly** for users, to route them through your site structure), and
- real site structure (which is only for search engines / crawlers, so they have as few as possible troubles on the way to each content piece)

Going from this, your real site structure should be (in the best case)

- start page

  - category page
  - detail page (notice, that the category and the detail pages are on the same nesting level a step deeper as the start page)

This structure can be crawled with the maximal efficiency.

Your menu (and breadcrumbs) can link to any content piece you mean will be helpful / handy for your users.

Comment: so what does this mean in overall. Which menu structure should be followed?