# Custom and readable urls for products in e-commerce

Tags: seo

I am building a simple e commerce shop and I wonder Should I build custom url for every product. I mean like this https://mywebsite.com/cars/bmw-x5

Instead of just using an id: https://mywebsite.com/cars/1

Will it be better for seo/

Comment: You will want to read this answer: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: We get quite a lot of these questions here, the one marked as a duplicate is specific to ID's versus slugs in URLs. Wexford's answer there should give you enough information, though anyone can add an answer there as well.