# Advice on URL structure

Tags: seo, url, search-engines

I'm looking for some advice on my URL structure for a project I'm working on. I'm a web developer so my SEO knowledge is relatively limited. My website's purpose is to essentially provide specialised information on a whole bunch of products. I have a fixed, 4-level structure for my product database which comprises of:

```
Category > Subcategory > Type > Product
```

All of the products I provide information on should fit into this structure. For example, I could have:

```
Household > Cleaning > Washing-up liquid > Product name here
```

My product database feature of my website currently sits under the path `/products`. My URLs are currently as follows:

```
/products
/products/household
/products/household/cleaning
/products/household/cleaning/washing-up-liquid
/products/household/cleaning/washing-up-liquid/product-name-here
```

The reason I'm asking for advice is because I fear my URLs are too long, particularly for product pages. Categories, sub-categories and types as well as product names can be significantly longer than in my examples and words could be repeated, especially in product pages.

I was thinking maybe I could change the URL structure for a product page as follows:

```
/product/product-name-here

OR

/product/1234/product-name-here
```

Would this be a better approach? I could keep the current structure for all of my category, subcategory and type pages or perhaps I could change them to be of a similar format. I'm open to any suggestions you might have.

Thanks!

**Edit**

Where my question is similar to the one it's marked as a duplicate of, I don't believe it's asking the same thing. That question seems to regard putting keywords earlier in the URL structure in order to carry more weight. My question is about the length of my URLs. I've read previously about URLs having an upper limit on length and the number of levels of hierarchy. I don't feel like that the answer to that question answers my own.

Comment: Where my question is similar to that one, I don't believe it's an exact duplicate. That question seems to regard putting keywords earlier in the URL structure in order to carry more weight. My question is about the length of my URLs. I've read previously about URLs having an upper limit on length and the number of levels of hierarchy.

Comment: Aside: "I'm a web developer so my SEO knowledge is relatively limited."?!

Comment: Yeah, relatively limited, as in I don't pretend to know a huge amount but it isn't non-existent. What's your point? Do you have anything to add in response to my question?

Comment: Some of your examples are very good. It all boils down to organization and what is important. Please do read my answer on the linked question above even if it does not seem to apply. It may help.

Answer (score 2):

See page 8-9 on the Google page SEO guidelines

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

> Opinion based: Matching URL's with titles & menus is best practice in
>   my view.
>
> **Avoid hashes** - URL's - same as titles should be human readable and *in best case helpful to the sub-cautious mind to identify the content*
>   that can be expected - if it reveals the site structure even better.
>   Hashes are justified if it avoids keyword stuffing or over lengthy
>   URL's.
>
> Every layer of subcategories adds complexity which isn't in best
>   interest of the user if its self-explaining. For example if you solely
>   list household products on the website i don't see any need to include
>   that

Comment: As comented by Steve http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/16250/steve  | Possible duplicate but i miss simplicity on these answers - anyhow, good thoughts too http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo