# WordPress subcategories and SEO

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, categories

I have questions about categories. Is it okay to have child (nested categories)?

For example:

```
Software Development
-- Web
---- Java Script
---- PHP
---- HTML 5
-- Low level
---- C 
---- Assembly
```

What impact will regarding SEO and search engines?
In this case there three categories are just wrappers that won't contain any posts *Software Development*, *Web* and *Low level*.

How will such structure of categories affect SEO?

**EDIT**

For example `URL` of post `Hello World` in following category hierarchy

```
 Software Development
    -- Mobile Development
    ---- Android development
```

Will be

```
domain.com/software-development/mobile-development/android-development/hello-world/
```

For me personally it looks ugly. `Development` word is very redundant. But what about search engines ?

Comment: This answer may help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 As well, it recommended that you be specific, development versus web development. The latter is far better.

Comment: @closetnoc thanks for reply, what is your opinion on categories structure ? Btw, my question contains not `development` versus `web development` but `web` category (which is inside `software development`) vs `web development` (which is also inside `software development`)

Comment: There were two distinct questions here. I've edited the question down tot the one which is clearly the focus here.

Comment: It all depends upon your content. I found that as I develop content, I end up making adjustments to the structure. One advice I give to people is to take an old PC and create a web server and begin posting there. Practice and developing some content before going live can really help you get it right from the start. As for development, it would depend on how developed these categories end up being. I have found that I end up developing content in one area that is strong and another area that is weak enough to drop.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the broader the topic, such as development, you may find that you have bitten off more than you can chew. It can really take a lot of time to develop content. I have found that finding one focus works better. You can always offer more later. It is better to narrow the focus then broaden the focus when you near the end of your current effort.

Comment: @closetnoc This example with development categories is just example I am not going to write about everything, firstly because I don't know all that stuff, but I am just asking from search engine and user perspective is better to separate categories like this hierarchically or just keep categories like `android-development`, `java-script-development` .... 
I have just updated my answer, please have a look

Comment: Again, it all depends on your content. You are right about using a single term too much. Be natural. If you can, your URI should almost read like a sentence or single thought. For example, /development/web/mobile/android/. From a semantics perspective, this is almost perfect.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you post it as answer to this question I will check it. 
One more question, for example when someone tries to find articles about `Android developmen` most of people type the same in google searh `Android Development`, but in my case I guess it won't be found because the name of category is `Android` and not `Android Development` am I right ? So, what would you choose in my case. Thx

Comment: It is all about semantics. Google does not make keyword matches and never really has. Any apparent term match was simply the last step of a fairly long process of applying algorithms where search terms are highlighted when done. Semantics is largely topics based analysis. This means that web, development, and Android are all related to the same topic and/or sub-topics. This is, in part, how Google knows to match search intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you can always have nested categories in WordPress (and most other CMSs) as well as child pages, child posts, grandchildren, etc.

If done in a non-spammy fashion, there is no real advantage or disadvantage from the pure SEO perspective...the spiders don't particularly care so long as the links work and the content is indexable. The big worry is creating a spammy-looking site that appears to abuse common keywords.  As a rule of thumb I never go lower than grandchildren:

```
 Software Development
    -- Mobile Development
    ---- Android development <---- no lower.
```

and try to avoid repeating the same terms in categories (e.g. "development" above). So a good replacement for the above could be:

```
Development
   -- Mobile
   ---- Android
   ---- iOS
```

That should handle most spam concerns.

The other reason to avoid long, nested categories is simple UX. I can remember and type `yoursite.com/development/mobile/android/`pretty easily but `yoursite.com/software-development/mobile-development/android-development/`makes me tired just looking at it. So always keep humans in mind when creating nice permalinks and the SEO benefit should follow automatically.

Comment: Thanks for great answer, I have one more question. What is better to use for category name not url. For example `Android` or `Android Development` of course `URL` will be simply `android`

Comment: Again, it doesn't really matter to the search engines assuming all parent or grandparent terms are visible. For humans, of course "Android Development" is preferred as it makes semantic sense. This is the point @closetnoc was making, so hat tip to him for inspiring my answer.