# How to choose right category names for a programming blog?

Tags: seo, categories

If I have a new blog with programming tutorial articles, Is it ok for SEO to have categories like "Web", "Network", "Game",... or It should be like "Web Development", "Network Programming", "Game Development"...?

Comment: @Martijn is perfectly correct about content first. Create content and do not worry too much about anything else. You will need about 300 posts before you begin to worry about anything else. This answer will help with some background regarding URIs and category structures. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 It should give you some ideas. Again, worry about this when you have content (not making any assumptions). Cheers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The time you're spending on *this* should be spent on creating good content.**

Content will have a much much greater effect on your ranking than some category name. Rewriting an article to make it more interesting for the reader will be worth 10 times as much* as this. Keeping your readers interested in your page, making them stay longer and come back should be your main focus.

**Figure of speech, not an actual statistic*

Comment: Thank you Martijn, I had read some articles about category/tag naming and it results on seo and I was concerned about this, But now I think you're right. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to go with categories like network, web or game then these kind of categories will land in the generic terms of seo. Have relevant categories for your blog.

I think "Web Development", "Network Programming", "Game Development" will work best for your niche.

Do the competitive research to find what others are doing in your industry. You will get good idea about the terms that you can use as your categories.

Comment: Thank You Prashant Gorule, I think we can also have categories with short keywords and use long keywords in tags instead. Please tell me if I'm wrong. But according to @Martijn answer, for now I'm trying to have quality contents for my blog.

Comment: Yes, the category with short keywords will work. Also I am agree with @Martijn on quality content for your blog.