# Is there any SEO difference between /blog and /blogs?

Tags: seo, url

In trying to categorize posts in a blog I'd like to use `/blogs` in the domain. Will this have any negative SEO impact? Or is it the same as `/blog` ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be blog or blogs - it can be anything that would really make sense to your current and future potential visitors in conjunction with the content you will provide through the pages. However always take into consideration the readability of your urls and how memorizable they can be. Having said that, blog is a very common term to be used and something everyone is familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

Google is specifically looking for blogs, however, it is not necessary for you to use either `/blog` or `/blogs`. Google will figure it out just fine. However, if you want to send a signal, there really is only one clear choice, `/blog`. Look around the web and you will not generally see `/blogs`. `/blog` or `/blogs`, Google will understand both.

From a user perspective it can be annoying.

From a semantic perspective, it adds no value.

Personally, I do not recommend either, however, if you held a gun to my head for an opinion, I would say `/blog`.

This answer does not address your question, however, it can be useful for you in the future: [Well structured URLs vs. URLs optimized for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639)

Answer (score 0):

For me, there is no difference between blog and blogs. While you searching inside the Google Search engine. It is not necessary for you to use either `/blog` or `/blogs`. I google it always show you the same results. But in SEO `/blogs` term is mostly used.