# SEO for repurposing a URL and moving already indexed content to a new URL

Tags: seo, url, content

I need to shift a page to another URL, so I can use the current URL of that page for another content. Can this be done without problems for Google?

Let's explain the situation.

Current situation:

```
Page A (it's already indexeed)
URL: example.com/formula-1
Content: ContentPageA
```

Desired situation:

```
Page A
URL: example.com/formula-1
Content: NEW CONTENT

Page B
URL: example.com/formula-1-news
Content: ContentPageA (the content that was in page A!)
```

Content in Page A and Page B will be about the same argument but different content (one is an overview, the other is a news list).
The other solution I have is to use a new URL for the new page of course, but if this can be done without problems for SEO, I prefer to use the URL example.com/page-a for the new content.

Comment: While this answer does not address your question directly, it may help anyhow: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 I am suggesting using directories such as /news for your work. It is better for search performance and just plain cleaner. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, you can do this.

Just away from duplicate content & URL, because duplicate content & URL can spam your website, google ranking down if your website on spam.

As per your note i am sure without duplicate content your website will not an any issue.

Answer (score 0):

This question is nearly impossible to answer correctly without knowing what content will be replaced and what content is replacing it. You've given us a basic explanation, however every detail matters in this situation. There are many aspects that should play into your decision here. Not only the content that will be replacing your current content, but your traffic, keyword rankings, and many other metrics related to this page. The question is far too vague, so I'd just recommend that you elaborate a bit more so you can avoid making a mistake. Every scenario is different.