# Should I block new low value category pages

Tags: seo, site-structure

I run a job board, which has three different taxonomies; category, location and job type.

I currently have all my category and location pages indexed by Google. They've been in the indexed for many years and rank well.

After requests from our user base, we will soon be creating combination pages. For example, a specific page for Bar Jobs (category) in Melbourne (location).

These will look like:

```
domain.com/jobs/bar-jobs/melbourne/
```

My concern is that this will create many new URLs.

Should I allow Google to index these pages or will the content difference be too weak?

The H1, Page Title, Meta Description and introductory paragraph or text will all be different to best describe the new pages - but I'm still concerned about best practice.

Secondly, at some point I would also like to introduce job type pages. This again will increase the number of URLs on the site.

For example;

```
domain.com/part-time/ (all part time jobs)
domain.com/part-time/bar-jobs/ (all part time bar jobs)
domain.com/part-time/melbourne/ (all part time jobs in Melbourne)
domain.com/part-time/bar-jobs/melbourne/
```

This could create 100-300 new URLs.

This will also create an opportunity to target many long tail key phrases. I would like benefit from searches such as "part time jobs Melbourne" but I don't want to harm the rest of the site.

What is best practice here?

Comment: I do not know how to answer your question. I do not create sites that have these kinds of pages, however, I will be soon enough and I am interested in the answer. I guess it depends upon how much of the content is duplicated or if there is a value-add to the page besides the organization of the content. I did think I should point out this answer I wrote some time ago about organizing the URL: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639 While it does not answer your question, I thought it could help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google fully understands and appreciates content that appears multiple times over various pages due to taxonomies and categories found in WordPress and other platforms, it is absolutely fine for those pages to be indexed because if they are useful for your users they are useful to be indexed, just as millions of other sites including all STACKS which have hundreds of thousands of these types of pages indexed.

Just ensure your site is setup to use [canonical links](https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/).

Answer (score 0):

This may be cause problem and taken and duplicate content even the titles are different , So you should not allow google search to index it . If you plan to removed indexed urls then use 410 redirect to prevent the traffic drop

Comment: Sorry but that is not true... much has changed since SEO 2004. With canonical links it is absolutely fine for duplicate text to be found on multiple tag and category pages, is why Google invented canonicals.