# Do similar products across different categories affect SEO?

Tags: seo, ecommerce, site-structure

If I have one category

- Long Sleeve T-Shirt

With its products

- Family Long Sleeve T-Shirt
- Children Long Sleeve T-Shirt
- Vintage Long Sleeve T-Shirt

Now I have another category

- Jersey T-Shirt

But basically it also has similar products

- Family Jersey T-Shirt
- Children Jersey T-Shirt
- Vintage Jersey T-Shirt

What's the best way to deal with the similarity for SEO purpose?

Do I just use the same structure as above or is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer help? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Very useful. But I think it's different from what I need. I'm not asking about optimizing URLs, but optimizing Site Structure. So instead of making 2 products "Long Sleeve T-Shirt" and "Jersey T-Shirt" with 3 variants (Family, Children, Vintage) for each product, I create 6 different products for 2 categories so I can have a page that target the keywords "Family, Children, Vintage". But it's a little crazy if I have more categories, like Tanktop, Hoodie. Then all of them will need to have 3 different products to target "Family, Children, and Vintage". Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The challenge with the structure you mention is that it could lead itself to "duplicate" content for search engines, and search engines might be forced to "choose" a category, skewing traffic towards this category. Have you considered differentiation by content? Ie making sure you uniquely describe/add text for long sleeve tshirts and jersey t shirts?

However, if you do choose to invest effort in structuring the site so that the categories do not compete with each other, I would recommend using a super category (eg "shirts"), and then have breadcrumbs which help users and search engines understand hierarchy and navigate to products.