# Will using a keyword twice in a URL hurt SEO?

Tags: seo, url, keywords

I have category in my permalinks in the format - `example.com/category/few-keywords` for my WordPress blog. Now, the category itself is one of the keyword which can get repeated in the latter half to make it more readable for the end user.

From the SEO and user's point of view, should I include the category keyword again?

Examples:

1. `example.com/chrome/extensions-to-block-sites-in-chrome/`
2. `example.com/chrome/extensions-to-block-sites/`

Which one of these is better? Will Google punish to have keyword twice in URL?

Comment: Just saw another article which gives a better example. The page title is "Google Maps New Update Suggests Ideal Time To Leave For A Place
" so the URL should be domain.com/maps/google-maps-update-suggest-ideal-time/ or domain.com/maps/update-suggest-ideal-time/

Comment: This answer should help. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say before you think about SEO, think about website structure first.

You can use your example 1 or 2, there will be no issue. Repeat in the page URL would be fine and even if you don't include that would be OK too.

Note that having a keyword in URL is good but you shouldn't think too much about it and don't over do it.

What I am hinting at is making it more meaningful and don't worry if you need to repeat it.

If I had to create the URL then i would go like this:

> example.com/chrome/best-extensions-to-block-websites-in-google-chrome/

Here, the category (/chrome) is short which is nice. I have increased the page URL a bit by having few extra words to make it more meaningful.

**Key Points:**

- URL: Make it short but meaningful.
- If you need to increase the length but if that will be more meaningful then go ahead and do that.
- Don't worry about 1 or in worse case 2 repeats.
- Your intention should be to make it more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

From a user's perspective I would include the 'keyword' again. The example of Google Maps simply is more readable with a second reference compared to just listing it in the category.

Personally I wouldn't worry about SEO on this specific level. If you're including the keyword in the URL once that should be more than enough for Google to recognize it under normal circumstances.

On the other hand, including it an 'unnatural' amount of times (I would say 3+ in this context) might lead to issues.

Stick to whatever feels best and place the user experience over 'pure SEO' in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Even I believe that URL should look natural and should be according to the user instead of being according to Google. But at the same time, if you read the entire URL, the second one looks natural whereas first one (where the keyword is repeated) looks like repeated words.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to me is YES. When Google's Panda and Penguin algorithms rolled out, the reported sites that were hit had nothing but URLs that were specifically targeted at spammy keywords and keyword variations. I will worry if the keywords you are targeting have a lot of competition or high search volume.

Now, the most important thing to consider is the usability you are providing with your site structure considering your main goals or website purpose.

To me these two URLs belongs to two different websites

```
example.com/chrome/extensions-to-block-sites-in-chrome/
example.com/extensions/block-sites-in-chrome/
```

Does your site structure help the user take quick actions to find the information they are looking for?

Long URLs has also usability problems

Have you considered:

```
example.com/chrome/blocking-site-extentions
```

By looking just at either url I have doubts, What Kind of sites am I blocking? how about:

```
example.com/chrome/bad-site-block-extentions
```

See where I am going?
In general avoid thinking just in keywords, give preference to memorable shorts URLs, make it descriptive as possible and try to avoid "stop words".

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you want to taking leverage of using keyword in url as a part of one page SEO. So it's recommend by Pro to use keyword in url. However, you're afraid of using keywords twice in your URL parameter. Assuming that you're not going to do or make cloaking or doorway page. After that you're safe of using that. Because you are just creating another sub resources page within the word phase.

for example

```
websitedotcom/link-building/blackhat-link-building


  websitedotcom/link-building/whitehat-link-building
```

So its making sense that it is safe to use.

Comment: Who is "Pro" that they recommend things?