# Would adding a "HOWTO guides" directory to my site's breadcrumbs and URL make a SEO difference?

Tags: seo

I currently have a "section" on my website which is only made different because of the breadcrumb that I use.

So it looks like this:

URL: `/svg/docs/howto-do-this-that-or-the-other.html`
BREADCRUMB: Home > SVG > Documentation and examples > How to do this that or the other

Would putting a bunch of the documentation pages (they're HOWTO guides) in their own dir make any difference [in terms of SEO value - so would the new structure be any better]? eg.

URL: `/svg/docs/howto/howto-do-this-that-or-the-other.html`
BREADCRUMB: Home > SVG > Documentation and examples > HOWTO guides > How to do this that or the other

(Note the addition of the howto dir in the URL)

Comment: Do what is right for users.

Comment: The only benefit that I can see is allowing people to directly go back to the list of HOWTO guides, though now I think about it both methods could do that  quite easily. So I don't think that there's a technical benefit either way. Maybe the second method is better semantically - but that's it I think.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: As far as bread crumbs are concerned, they are good for users so think in those terms, however, there is no SEO advantage to them anymore. Cheers!!

Comment: I just reread your title question. To answer that question simply, No not given the example you supplied. Why? It is redundant. If it were not, then sure. Why not?