# Multiple keywords in SEO friendly URL

Tags: seo, url, keywords, url-keywords

I have a website with the domain as ‘domain.tld’. I have a product let’s call it as ‘Name A’. The product is used for purpose say ‘Purpose 1 software’. Now I need to optimise the SEO of the product page for both product name and product purpose. So I decided to add the 2 keywords (‘Purpose 1 software’, ‘Name A’) in the page url. But what will be the best way to gain high SEO rankings for the product page with both the keywords? Using them in URLs as below examples?

1. domain.tld/product/Purpose-1-software/name-a/    ?
2. domain.tld/product/ Purpose-1-software /#name-a   ?
3. Or is there any other way?

Note: In the URL, I need to give more priority to ‘purpose 1 software’ rather than ‘name A’ as I target new customers. Purpose 1 software is only one part of the software. Actually, Name A is the multipurpose software and I would like to target that software for many purposes in the SEO.

Please let me know the best way to include those 2 keywords in the URL.

**Update**:

I can make any changes for the url/permalink since i am using wordpress for hosting my site.

Comment: Do you have any separated page for "Purpose-1-software" in your website?

Comment: no i only have the product page but i can make the changes in the title of the page as 'Purpose-1-software' to satisfy my 2nd example. For my first example i can even create the page so that i can achieve my 1st example.

Comment: If you use method 1, also have separate page for "Purpose-1-software" you have 2 benefits, first is you have more pages and it's mean more chance for leads, second one is you can better do targeted SEO.

Comment: Does this help? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo/74639#74639

Comment: Google doesn't rank pages better based on the URL right now.   Choose a URL that describes the content to users.   Users often react better when the URL is descriptive with keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to go for the most simple version: domain.tld/product/purpose-1-software-name-a/ "purpose-1-software" will be on the beginning of the path and at the last level, so it will get a slightly more value.