# SEO friendly best practice for putting id and title in different language

Tags: url, search-engine-indexing, seo, google-search, googlebot

I know there are very similar questions like this, but I didn't find the best answerer.
I have url like `site.com/:id1/:id2/:id3`
For having best result in SEO, someone told its better to put titles in url, and my titles are in different language.
These are suggested links:

1. `site.com/:id1/عنوان/:id2/عنوان/:id3/عنوان`
2. `site.com/:id1-عنوان/:id2-عنوان/:id3-عنوان`

or someone told instead of `id`, we can use enums, id1=>title1, id2=>titl2, ...

3. `site.com/title1/عنوان/title2/عنوان/title3/عنوان`

Which one is better solutions? or anyone has any other ideas ?

Comment: It's not clear what do title1, title2, etc represent. Are these just the string (enum) representations of IDs? In that case, it should not really matter if you use IDs vs Titles.

Comment: @GauravPhapale , yes its unique English text mapped to that ID. isn't it better to use 'apple' instead of ID '2' in url ?

Comment: I think it's a mistake to place too much emphasis on the words you use in your URL with SEO.  Read @closetnoc answer to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74633/well-structured-urls-vs-urls-optimized-for-seo.  They states, `keywords found in the URL/URI which are sometimes totally ignored because they are so common`  What is potentially more important is making your URL's human friendly.  What will your users likely type in if they want to type your complete URL?